# Android In-app billing Restore

Tags: android, in-app-billing

I want some clarification regarding **in-app billing android**.I uploaded an apk in draft state in google play..I created an **in-app product id** and i made a purchase with **test account registered with my developer account**..Purchase worked fine as intended..i deleted the uploaded apk from developer site and  also deleted the in-app product id.
      but the problem arose when i build a new  signed apk with restore function and i uploaded with the **new In-app product id** and when i installed the new apk with **same test account but different in-app product id,**it says **the purchase is already done and it restored the app**..
     can i know how restore function should work?? It should restore with different product id also? or it sees the registered google account with the in-app product?

Answer (score 0):

When you send a restore request, Google will send a PURCHASE_STATE_CHANGED notification with the original product ID purchased by the user account.

You might not be handling this notification correctly.